# Python matplotlib: how to let matrixplot have variable column widths

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a simple need but cannot find its simple solution. I have a matrix to plot, but I wish the row/columns to have given widths.

Something looking like a blocked matrix where you tell block sizes.

Any workaround with the same visual result is accepted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


samplemat = np.random.rand(3,3)
widths = np.array([.7, .2, .1])

# Display matrix
plt.matshow(samplemat)

plt.show()
```

[image: Usual outcome]

[image: Desired outcome (fake drawing)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matshow` or `imshow` work with equal sized cells. They hence cannot be used here. Instead you may use `pcolor` or `pcolormesh`. This would require to supply the coordinates of the cell edges.
Hence you first need to calculate those from the given width. Assuming you want them to start at 0, you may just sum them up.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(43)


samplemat = np.random.rand(3,3)
widths = np.array([.7, .2, .1])
coords = np.cumsum(np.append([0], widths))
X,Y = np.meshgrid(coords,coords)
# Display matrix
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,samplemat)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks! I would just do `X,Y = np.meshgrid(coords,1- coords)` to change the diagonal side.